# How to login as super user?

Tags: permissions

I use the Ubuntu 12.04TLS and I believe I am the admin user. However when I create a file (for example using editor like Sublime Text2) and save it in my `var/www/` folder, it always pop `Unable to save /var/www/filename`. It is so annoying that I have to create the file somewhere first (for example Dektop) and use terminal, login as SU and mv filename to `/var/www/` directory.

I believe this is a permission issue. How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To open Sublime Text 2 with root privileges, use terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo sublime-text
```

Comment: It says "Command not found".

Comment: I just installed it on 12.04, and tried it.  It works.  How did you install it?